# Convert jQuery slick.js to angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

I was trying to convert my jQuery to angularjs directive, I don't know what I am doing wrong in the code below, can someone tell what I am doing wrong? I am very new into angular and I dont understand why this code is not working?

html:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide-block">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-exchange"></i>
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-block">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-exchange"></i>
    <h4 > 2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('components').directive('slick', [
      'jquery',
      function slick($) {
        'use strict';

        var
          scope = {};

        function link($scope, $element) {


              $('.slider').slick({
          centerMode: false,
          infinite: false,
          centerPadding: '2px',
          slidesToShow: 6,
          speed: 200,
          index: 2,

          variableWidth: true,
          responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerMode: true,
              centerPadding: '40px',
              slidesToShow: 3
            }
          }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerMode: true,
              centerPadding: '40px',
              slidesToShow: 1
            }
          }]
        });

        }

        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: scope,
          templateUrl: 'slick.html',
          link: link
        };
      }
    ]);
```

Comment: Don't know why it's not working but you should use $element instead of `$('.slider')` so it works also if you use the directive multiple times

Comment: I tried this but still not working

Comment: if I do a console.log inside my function link, does not appear and looks like the fucntion is not running

Answer (score 0):

There are already a couple of angular modules that does just this. Check them out!

https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick 
https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel